# Exchange 2010 to O365 Hybrid - Keep Public Folders changable

Tags: exchange-2010, public-folders, exchangeonline, exchange-hybrid

The company I am performing an Exchange 2010 to Office 365 migration for has public folders.

We planned to perform the migration while the two systems are in hybrid mode, over the course of several weeks, using the following guide for putting Public Folders in hybrid mode - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/collaboration-exo/public-folders/set-up-legacy-hybrid-public-folders

I have read that while you can put Public Folders in hybrid mode, migrated users can only access a read-only copy of them.

Not sure about other companies use of Public Folders, but this company has employees altering content daily in them, so weeks with an ever increasing quantity of employees being unable to change content in Public Folders is not acceptable.

Do I understand this read-only hybrid setup correctly, or is there 3rd party solutions someone can point me to in order to resolve this issue?

Comment: You haven't told us what methods or tools you're using to migrate the Public Folders but do yourself a favor (and save yourself some pain) and use a third party tool. I've used this with great success - https://www.codetwo.com/office-365-migration/

Comment: @joeqwerty - Unfortunately the company isn't big and hence isn't able to spring for CodeTwo's offering. Besides, I am eager for the challenge. I have updated my question with the specific instructions I had planned to use to put Public Folders in hybrid mode.

Comment: OK, in your question you asked if there were third party solutions available. There are, which is what I referenced. Did you mean third party solutions that are free? If so, I'm not aware of any. For what it's worth, CodeTwo would cost you less than $250.00 USD.

Comment: Also, for what it's worth, I've done Public Folder migrations with Microsoft's native methods and have had no end of pain with it. I've used CodeTwo as well and have never had an issue. It's relatively straightforward, painless, and cost effective.

Comment: Fair point. So does CodeTwo's tools allow hybrid Public Folders to be editable by both still on-prem, and migrated mailboxes?

Answer (score 1):

Kernel Migrator for Exchange is another excellent tool for Exchange 2010 to Office 365 migration. You can try its free demo version to assess the software's functionality.